# How to find which address are enclosing a block in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, address

I have two separates shape files. The first one contains blocks and the second one contains roads with addresses. Which is the suitable method in order to find each block from which address is enclosed?

The issue is that I have to assign to every block all the road addresses that are surround every block, meaning that let's say: Block 1 is surrounding by a street, by b street, by c street, by d street, Block 2 is surrounding by a street, by b street, by c street, by E street etc. So I want to create a matrix that it will have all this information...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the attribute table of your address file?

Answer (score 1):

I think your first step should be to [Generate Near Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) which:

> Calculates distances and other proximity information between features
>   in one or more feature class or layer. Unlike the Near tool, which
>   modifies the input, Generate Near Table writes results to a new
>   stand-alone table and supports finding more than one near feature.

Comment: Before generating near table you may have to fix your streets layer. To get correct surroundings you need to have only one single line for each street. To get this - Dissolve line layer by field [StreetName] or something with 'Unsplit Lines' turned ON.

Comment: And it might be a good idea to convert your blocks to centroid points  and generate near table for it instead of polygons (or you might get some issues on crossroads)